# Error while starting tomcat server in eclipse for struts 2 web application

Tags: tomcat, struts2

I am trying to implement a sample web application using struts 2 in eclipse.
I have configured everything. But when I am starting tomcat it is displaying below error

> Sep 15, 2010 11:59:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>   SEVERE: Error filterStart
>   Sep 15, 2010 11:59:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>   SEVERE: Context startup failed due to previous errors

What could be the possible issue ?

below is the whole trace while starting tomcat.

> Sep 15, 2010 12:30:10 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
>   INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
>   Sep 15, 2010 12:30:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>   INFO: Initialization processed in 1062 ms
>   Sep 15, 2010 12:30:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
>   INFO: Starting service Catalina
>   Sep 15, 2010 12:30:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
>   INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.0.28
>   Sep 15, 2010 12:30:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
>   INFO: XML validation disabled
>   Sep 15, 2010 12:30:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>   SEVERE: Error filterStart
>   Sep 15, 2010 12:30:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>   SEVERE: Context startup failed due to previous errors
>   Sep 15, 2010 12:30:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost getDeployer
>   INFO: Create Host deployer for direct deployment ( non-jmx )
>   Sep 15, 2010 12:30:19 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
>   INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
>   Sep 15, 2010 12:30:19 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
>   INFO: JK2: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
>   Sep 15, 2010 12:30:19 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
>   INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/47  config=null
>   Sep 15, 2010 12:30:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   INFO: Server startup in 9388 ms

Comment: what are the previous errors in the log? Post those

Comment: Is there a catalina.log file or any Tomcat errors in your eclipse\workspace\.metadata\*log files?

Comment: I got the issue and fixed it. Thanks JoseK for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is with the version of Tomcat. Earlier I was using tomcat 5. Now I switched to tomcat 6. It got fixed.